# file upload to server took time to complete

Tags: php, file-upload

I tried to upload an image using localhost was upload instantly, however, when tried on my webhosting, it took more than 5 mins for the file to appear in "_uploads" folder.

Do anyone encounter the same problem? Does AV took account for the delay in scanning?

```
<?php
$hasError = false;foreach( $_FILES as $i=>$file ){
    if ( $file['error'] ){
        $hasError = true;
    }
}
if ( ! $hasError ){
    $filename = '_uploads/'.$_GET["key"].'_'.$file["name"];
    $myFilePath = '_uploads/'.$_GET["key"].'_'.$file["name"];
    $dta = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents($myFilePath, $dta);
    echo('success');
} else {
    echo('Image was not successfully upload.');
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you resolve? I'll try and assist further is your still having problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

It uses the **move_uploaded_file** method below which I think is a more efficient way of moving the file rather than **file_get_contents** and **file_put_contents**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

If your not already checking I'd make sure you check the files uploaded are valid by checking there mime type and extension type.

Here is the link to the PHP reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: will try your method

but $_FILES["file"] <- the file in the quote can be named in way I like? since I transfer from Actionscript to PHP

Comment: Should be able to pass it's location in however you have it stored. Your code example doesnt seem complete enough to help any further but I'm sure this will speed things up for you!

:)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the file.

On localhost the file doesn't have top be transfered over the internet.

What size is the file?

You may also want to check out `move_uploaded_file` rather than `file_put_contents`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

Comment: less than 50kb of image, will try your method.